# How to insert single quotes in double quotes in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax, string-concatenation, quotation-marks

I'm trying to insert single Quotation marks inside a double quotation marks... 
Beginning Quotation mark like this `"“"` ..... and ending Quotation mark like this `"”"` ...

My code:

```
objWriter.WriteLine("<li>" + "“" + "<em>" + BP1.Text + "</em>" + "”" + " ― " + "<strong>" + BPGB1.Text + "</strong>" + "</li>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st:

The characters that you mentioned are not a single quote, are a double quote.

- **[Left Double Quotation Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201C/)**
- **[Right Double Quotation Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/)**

2nd:

In **Vb.Net**, unlike **C#**, string concatenations are made with the `&` operator, avoid using the `+` operator, it will give you **[unexpected results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx)** in some scenarios.

---

The **Visual Studio**'s code editor automaticaly replaces the characters that you've mentioned with a common double quote, however, knowing the Unicode references you can get the specific characters at execution time then concat them as normally or using the **[String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** method in this way:

```
Dim lQuotes As Char = Convert.ToChar(&H201C) ' “
Dim rQuotes As Char = Convert.ToChar(&H201D) ' ”

Dim str As String = String.Format("{0}Hello World{1}", lQuotes, rQuotes)

Console.WriteLine(str) ' “Hello World”
```

### UPDATE

An example with the string that you've provided:

```
Dim lQuotes As Char = Convert.ToChar(&H201C) ' “
Dim rQuotes As Char = Convert.ToChar(&H201D) ' ”

Dim str As String =
    String.Format("<li>{0}<em>{2}</em>{1} ― <strong>{3}</strong></li>",
                  lQuotes, rQuotes, BP1.Text, BPGB1.Text)

objWriter.WriteLine(str)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to show this result in the code that I've given in my question ??? Becoz I'm really novice to the .Net

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand why u have used {0}{2}{1}{3} and i'm seeing that there's no objWriter.WriteLine code, I really want this inorder to write to a text file... I'm a complete novice here so I'm sorry

Comment: The `{n}` means the parameter index after the string format, so `{0}` = lQuotes, `{1}` = rQuotes, `{2}` BP1.Text and `{3}` = BPGB1.Text, the values are inserted at the position on where are written those `{n}` in the string format. About the Stream, you just should do: `objWriter.WriteLine(str)` with the resulting string.

Comment: Wowww... That worked like wonders... It's exactly what I want ... Thanks dude... You are the genius

Comment: @winnu You're welcome to StackOverflow :). I'm glad to help. but please remember to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your doubts. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used the wrong character for single quotation:

```
objWriter.WriteLine("<li>" + "'" + "<em>" + BP1.Text + "</em>" + "'" + " ― " + "<strong>" + BPGB1.Text + "</strong>" + "</li>")
```

Comment: I used the right characters, but May be i said wrongly in my question... I really meant the double quotations

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this works or not:

```
objWriter.WriteLine("<li>" & "““" & "<em>" + BP1.Text + "</em>" + "””" + " ― " + "<strong>" + BPGB1.Text + "</strong>" + "</li>")
```

or maybe even this

```
objWriter.WriteLine("<li>" & ““““ & "<em>" + BP1.Text + "</em>" + ”””” + " ― " + "<strong>" + BPGB1.Text + "</strong>" + "</li>")
```

Comment: I need a 1 double quotation inside the quotes... But I guess u have used 2

Comment: @winnu The two double-quotes are used to escape the double quote char, the example is right when the intention is to insert a common double quote ("), but with your Unicode characters that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the &"""" with chr(24)

so you would have something like this objWriter.WriteLine("

" & chr(34 ) & chr(34) & "*" + BP1.Text + "*. . . . .